# custom model binder with T4MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, modelbinders, t4mvc

I have a custom model binder in my MVC app but I don't know hos I can use T4MVC with it.

Usualy I would Call my action this way :

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Version", new {contractId = contract.Id.ToString()});
```

With T4MVC it should be like this :

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Version.Edit(contract));
```

But since T4 does'nt know about my binder, he try to send the object in the url but what I want is that he generate the url like this : Contract/{contractId}/Version/{action}/{version}

Also note that I have a custom route :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Version", // Route name
                "Contract/{contractId}/Version/{action}/{version}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Version", action = "Create", version = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

This is my binder :

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var contractId = GetValue(bindingContext, "contractId");
            var version = GetA<int>(bindingContext,"version");

            var contract = _session.Single<Contract>(contractId);
            if (contract == null) 
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
            }
            var user = _authService.LoggedUser();
            if (contract.CreatedBy == null || !contract.CreatedBy.Id.HasValue || contract.CreatedBy.Id.Value != user.Id)
            {
                throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized");
            }

            if (contract.Versions.Count < version)
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, "Not found");
            }
            return contract;
        }
```

What should I do? I don't want to have magic string in my route...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
return RedirectToAction(MVC.Version.Edit().AddRouteValues(new {contractId = contract.Id.ToString()}));
```

Answer (score 1):

And now the same could be achieved with [ModelUnbinders](https://github.com/T4MVC/T4MVC/wiki/Documentation#31-using-model-unbinders).
You could implement custom unbinder:

```
public class ContractUnbinder : IModelUnbinder<Contract>
{
    public void UnbindModel(RouteValueDictionary routeValueDictionary, string routeName, Contract contract)
    {
        if (user != null)
            routeValueDictionary.Add("cityAlias", contract.Id);
    }
}
```

and then register it in T4MVC (from Application_Start):

```
ModelUnbinderHelpers.ModelUnbinders.Add(new ContractUnbinder());
```

After that you can normally use MVC.Version.Edit(contract) for generating urls.